# Convert HTML to image in php

Tags: php, image-processing, php-gd

I have to create a PNG / JPEG image from PHP script .. Briefly

The code will create a html table and will include an image in that page. I need to save this entire page as an image , save that image in my server and return the path of the image ( using webservice ).

I can create image from imagejpg function pretty well . My problem is how to convert that HTML to image, Cant take a screen shot because the processes going on through web services .

Please help me to convert HTML to image using php

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just created full HTML page including MAP .... I have to convert this entire html to image .. Please help .. I have to share HTML code ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can download wkhtmltoimage from [this link](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list). There is a version for all operating systems so that shouldn't be a problem. Then you can use it like so:

```
$path="wkhtmltoimg/wkhtmltoimage.exe"; //path to your executable
$url="http://google.com";
$output_path="test.png";
shell_exec("$path $url $output_path");
```

One thing you want to note is that if PHP is in safe mode, shell_exec will not work and you won't be able to do your conversion.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PHP PhantomJS](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs) to save a screen capture of a HTML page to the local disk:

```
<?php

use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;

$client = Client::getInstance();

$width  = 800;
$height = 600;
$top    = 0;
$left   = 0;

$request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createCaptureRequest('http://example.com', 'GET');
$request->setOutputFile('/path/to/save/capture/file.jpg');
$request->setViewportSize($width, $height);
$request->setCaptureDimensions($width, $height, $top, $left);

$response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

// Send the request
$client->send($request, $response);
```