# Upload html2canvas image to database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html2canvas

Is it possible to upload the image html2canvas gives, to database.
Bassically when i click Save, it redirects me to save.php where i can see the screenshot i made, view the image, and view the image locally on my local server.

The main question is, can a form be made, where on save.php i will be able to save the image as a random number (etc 32245652226225.jpg) into a specific folder and insert the value into database with values: img_name , img_date

Then i could retrive all the images from database, and sort them by date.
I would appreciate any help.

This is the result i got
[image: result]

This is my index.php

```js
 function capture() {
  $('#target').html2canvas({
   onrendered: function (canvas) {
                //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
    $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                //Submit the form manually
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
   }
  });
 }
```

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php" id="myForm">
 <input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Sacuvaj" onclick="capture();" />

<div id="target">
  <h1>TESTING</h1>
</div>
```

And this is the save.php

```html
<?php
//Get the base-64 string from data
$filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

//Decode the string
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

//Save the image
file_put_contents('slika.jpg', $unencodedData);
?>
<h2>Screenshoot</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="slika.jpg" target="blank">folder</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <a href="index.php">nazad</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <br />
            <br />
   <span>
   
   </span>
            <br />
<?php
//Show the image
echo $_POST['img_val'];
echo '<img class="img-responsive" src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />';
?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<style type="text/css">
body, a, span {
 font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold;
}
img{
 width:400px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes you can save then using PHP..Show us what you have tried so far...You must be having `BASE64` of the image to be uploaded..You can convert that data as image file over server..

Comment: Yes sorry for the code, i will upload the rusult i got so far and the code.thank you

Comment: Ok so i have uploaded my result image and my code. Any ideas how to solve what i need . Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES ;)

I mean, it seems like you found the puzzle pieces yourself already:

- capture the screen on client
- submit that via a form to the server
- write meta info like capture date to a database which returns you unique ID numbers (any number id)
- copy the file to a folder with the filename adhering to the file ID (and appy some logic to create a new subfolder on every 4 digits of your file ID)
- have another script that helps you to search for images and to display them

If you actually ask for a free of charge coding service I am sorry to say that I cannot help you. Anyway, for database accesses there are nice tutorials out there, if you are just lacking some basic knowledge on that edge.

---

Btw. maybe rendering the html to img on server side might even be better:
[Convert HTML to image in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732114/convert-html-to-image-in-php)