# Converting HTML output to BLOB image

Tags: php, html, database, url, blob

I want to make a some step of saving data into DB as BLOB data type. I need convert data to BLOB in the DB. I have the data that are considered as HTML output in the some file. The selected programming language is PHP with Zend Framework 1 and database is MySQL.

I tried to save HTML page as valid BLOB image in DB, but it is still not working. I can't find any solutions about it and I don't know how to do. When I got a content from URL and saved it into DB as BLOB by using function file_get_contents($url), that is worked to me fine.

Here is a code that saves the content of the HTML page in the file described below into DB as BLOB.

```
$file = "C:\test.html";
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($file));
fclose($fp);
$dbModel = new MyTable($this->db);
$dbRowSet = $dbModel->find(1);
$dbRow = $dbRowSet->current();
$dbRow->map = $content;
$dbRow->save();
```

Here is a preview of saved HTML page in DB, but there I can't show any BLOB image.
[image: image 1]

There is shown BLOB image. I had the URL page and tried to save it into DB.
[image: image 2]

I expected that the result of saving data (HTML page) into DB should be that DB contains valid BLOB images.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to save and display an image as a blob?

Comment: your question is too unclear to provide answer to, could you be more specific about the problem statement, as far as I understand, you are having trouble in saving an image as BLOB in the database. Is it the case?

Comment: _“I expected that the result of saving data (HTML page) into DB should be that DB contains valid BLOB images.”_ - well, you expect wrong. When your HTML code gets parsed inside a browser, the browser finds those image URLs inside the HTML, and makes additional request to load those images. You have no browser involved here, you are _just_ storing HTML code into your database. There is no one here that would take care of actually requesting those images.

Comment: @BrettGregson I want to know how to save HTML page and display it as image

Comment: So you want to save HTML and display it as an image? What would you expect to display for `<div>Hello</div>`? An image containing the word "Hello"?

Comment: @BrettGregson yes, you expect same as what I would expect

Comment: I don't expect anything, I'm asking you so I can try help you. If you want to convert HTML to an image see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image

Answer (score 0):

You can download wkhtmltoimage from [this link](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/). There is a version for all operating systems so that shouldn't be a problem. Then you can use it like so:

```
$path="wkhtmltoimg/wkhtmltoimage.exe"; //path to your executable
$url="http://google.com";
$output_path="test.png";
shell_exec("$path $url $output_path");
```

One thing you want to note is that if PHP is in safe mode, shell_exec will not work and you won't be able to do your conversion.

Credit: @Tom
[Convert HTML to image in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732114/convert-html-to-image-in-php)

---

After this you just need [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and save blob in the database.

Comment: How is this supposed to answer OPs question? They want to save html as image

Comment: What I want is that:

`$url = 'temp/temp.html';`
`$path = 'temp/temp.png';`
`copy($url, $path);`

But this still can't be converted into image..

Comment: Holdon, you want to print HTML and show it like image???

Comment: I update my answer.